# Sum() is show double the value in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have three table Item, Puchesedetails, IssueStockDetails
when I create inner join and sum(QTY..) it show just double of value for example if Purches qty is 10 it show 20 if received qty is 15 it show 30

Here is my code

```
Select I.Item_Id, I.Item_Name, I.Specification, I.Item_HSN, I.unit, 
((I.QTY +  COALESCE(SUM(PUBD.ReceivedQTY),0)) - COALESCE(SUM(ISSUE.QTYIssue),0)) AS AVAILABLEQTY, 
COALESCE((PUBD.IssueStockRate),0) AS Rate, I.Serial_number_applied as SNA, 
I.QTY AS OPENINGQTY, Sum(PUBD.ReceivedQTY) AS RECIVEDQTY, Sum(ISSUE.QTYIssue) AS ISSUEQTY  
from Item I inner join purchasebilldetails PUBD on I.Item_Id = PUBD.ItemID and  inner JOIN issuestockdetails ISSUE ON ISSUE.ItemID=I.Item_Id 
WHERE  I.ComId=8 GROUP BY I.Item_Id, PUBD.IssueStockRate HAVING AVAILABLEQTY>0


If I have 3 table 
Item {ItemID, Name, QTY},
purchasebilldetails {ItemID, Name RecivedQTY},
issuestockdetails {ItemID, Name IssueQty},

what is the right way to get:
available QTY {Item Qty+ RecivedQTY},
RecivedQTY {sum of all received QTY},
IssueQty {sum of all Issue QTY},
```

Please Help

Comment: Isn't that your mistake in grouping `PUBD.IssueStockRate`? Isn't it better to write `PUBD.ItemID` instead? Please show us the sample data of the three tables and the query output ...

Comment: Your query is synthactically wrong. `... on I.Item_Id = PUBD.ItemID and  inner JOIN ...`

Comment: what is the right way to do ... on I.Item_Id = PUBD.ItemID and  inner JOIN ...